# Unknown column 'User.ucode' in 'field list' (localhost ok, hosting not ok)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm sorry for what looks like a stupid question, but I'm having a weird problem with my hosting server as the code is currently working on my own computer.

What I am trying to do is to query the fields `title`, `id`, and `category` from Content, and user's `ucode` from User into the following structure on each of the results:

```
{
    title: "Some title",
    id: "123456",
    category: "11",
    ucode: "123ABC"
}
```

...Then descending-sort it according to creation date. Here's how I queried, which already works on my computer and returned the structure I wanted:

```
//Relations
User.hasMany(Content, { foreignKey: 'userID' }); //userID is the PK of Users table
Content.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userID' });

//Query
Content.findAll({
    attributes: ["title", "id", "category", "User.ucode"],
    include: [{
        model: User,
        attributes: [],
        required: true
    }],
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    offset: offset,
    limit: 50,
    raw: true
}).then(...)
```

Error I got on my hosting, but not on localhost:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'User.ucode' in 'field list'\n
at Query.formatError ............
```

I don't know if this could be caused by version difference although minor, but my computer is running v8.9.4 while my hosting is on v8.9.3.

Does anyone here have some pointers? Thanks!

Comment: have you `migrated` `user` table in live?

Comment: I have fully reset the whole database and still no luck.

Comment: check your database and check if `User` field is present

Comment: By "field" do you mean my database column? If so, `User` is a model. And `ucode` exists as part of `User`'s table and (should be) queryable by specifying `User.ucode`. It does not exist explicitly in `Content` as `User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow... I just changed from `User.ucode` to `user.ucode` and it magically works. So the full query now becomes (also thanks to @Sravan):

```
Content.findAll({
    attributes: ["title", "id", "category", "user.ucode"],
    include: [{
        model: User,
        attributes: [],
        required: true
    }],
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    offset: offset,
    limit: 50,
    raw: true
}).then(...)
```

I'm still not sure why uppercase works on my computer but not on the hosting. But it's possibly because on my hosting the table is initialized as `user` instead of `User` somehow and/or being case-sensitive. Or maybe it is because I'm using MySQL 5.7 while the hosting uses 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Since user is a `separate model`, table name might be lowercase `user`

You should include `user.ucode`.

```
Content.findAll({
    attributes: ["title", "id", "category", "user.ucode"],
    include: [{
        model: Model2,
        attributes: [],
        required: true
    }],
    order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    offset: offset,
    limit: 50,
    raw: true
}).then(...)
```

Comment: this does change the structure a little bit though, as now the `ucode` is returned as `{"user.ucode": ....}`

Comment: can you send complete `response`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I somehow solved it just by changing `User.ucode` to `user.ucode`. I'm going to put this into my own answer

Comment: so, your table name might be `user` instead of User

Comment: Goo that you found that. I have updated the answer with the same, so that It might be useful to anyone

Comment: Is it possible that my problem is caused by MySQL version difference (my 5.7 vs host's 5.5)?

Comment: It also may be dependant on the `sequelize` version

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have the same sequelize version on server and on my dev pc. I think it really might just be the MySQL version difference. Anyways, thanks for helping!

Comment: yeah I l check those versions and code is same for model definitions in both?